# Error while updating scylladb schema using Liquibase Migration Tool in Intellij Idea

Tags: scala, liquibase, scylla

I'm new to Liquibase Migration Tool. I'm trying to update schema of Scylladb using Liquibase. For that I'm using Intellij Idea as IDE and Scala (version 2.13.1). First I add dependencies (Liquibase and Java Driver) in .sbt file.

**build.sbt (sbt version 1.2.8):**

```
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.1"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "scylladb_liquibase"
  )
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.liquibase" % "liquibase-core" % "4.5.0",
  "com.scylladb" % "scylla-driver-core" % "3.11.2.4"
)
```

Then I created one directory 'liquibase' at root level, and put changelog.sql file and liquibase.properties file in it.

**changelog.sql File:**

```
--liquibase formatted sql

--changeset zaryab:1
CREATE TABLE test01.TESTME1 ( foo int PRIMARY KEY, bar text );

--rollback DROP TABLE test01.TESTME1;

--changeset zaryab:2
CREATE TABLE test01.TESTME2 ( foo int PRIMARY KEY, bar text );

--rollback DROP TABLE test01.TESTME2;
```

**liquibase.properties:**

```
driver=com.scylladb.jdbc3.Driver
classpath=scylla-driver-core-3.11.2.4.jar
url=jdbc:scylla://172.17.0.2:9042/test01
```

**(Note: driver-core-3.11.2.4.jar file is inside 'liquibase' folder as well as inside src/main/resources folder)**

Then I created main class named 'LiquibaseExample.scala'.

```
import liquibase.Liquibase
import liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory
import liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection
import liquibase.resource.{ClassLoaderResourceAccessor, FileSystemResourceAccessor}

import java.io.File
import java.sql.DriverManager

object LiquibaseExample {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val props = new java.util.Properties()
    val fis = new java.io.FileInputStream(new File("liquibase/liquibase.properties"))
    props.load(fis)
    fis.close()
    val jdbcUrl = props.getProperty("url")
    val classpath = props.getProperty("classpath")
    Class.forName(classpath)
    val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl)
    val database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(connection))
    val liquibase = new Liquibase(props.getProperty("liquibase/changelog.sql"), new FileSystemResourceAccessor(), database)
    liquibase.update("")
  }
}
```

But it's giving exception 'ClassNotFoundException':

```
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scylla-driver-core-3.11.2.4.jar
[error] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scylla-driver-core-3.11.2.4.jar
[error]     at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:476)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
[error]     at LiquibaseExample$.main(LiquibaseExample.scala:37)
[error]     at LiquibaseExample.main(LiquibaseExample.scala)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[error] Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] (Compile / run) Nonzero exit code: 1
```

Kindly help me in this, how can I solve this issue?
Also help me, Am I doing it (updating scylladb schema using liquibase migration tool with java driver) right?

**Any help is appreciated.**

Answer (score 2):

You made a typo. You want `driver` instead of `classpath`:

```
val driver = props.getProperty("driver")
Class.forName(driver)
```

Note that you probably don't need these 2 lines at all.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It is working fine, but giving another ClassNotFoundException that is: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.scylladb.jdbc3.Driver. Is it necessary to use JDBC in order to update scylladb schema using Liquibase? I'm not able to find JDBC driver for scylladb on any browser.

Comment: https://java-driver.docs.scylladb.com/stable/